# manually enter a subtotal value in a vb6 flexgrid

Tags: vb6

I have a flexgrid with a grouping, and a .subtotal by that grouping. All columns except one are numeric, the one that isn't is in the format 'x/y' e.g. '1/5', i.e. 1 out of 5 items supplied.

if I do a .Subtotal with a flexSTSum it sums up the first number in the pair, i.e. in the above example it would sum up the 1 as a decimal and show 1.00 in the subtotal row

At first I tried to find a way to sum on another column, i.e. I could put individual values into separate columns, give them a .Width of 0 and sum these into the .Subtotal column of the first column, but I can't find a way to do that.

And even if I do find a way to do that I want to be able to custom format the .Subtotal, so it appears as '3/17', i.e. '1/5' and '2/12' subtotal to '3/17' in the subtotal row.

if I can't subtotal off another column I wondered if I could custom access the subtotal row and manually enter the subtotal value of '3/17', but even that seems unavailable.

My question is, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the VideoSoft FlexGrid which i never used, so I can't help you with the specific methods of that control.

You can do it easily with a standard MSFlexGrid control though, and you can probably do the same with the VideoSoft FlexGrid.

Have a look at the following sample project:

```
'1 form with :
'    1 msflexgrid control : name=MSFlexGrid1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long
  With MSFlexGrid1
    .Rows = 10
    .Cols = 4
    .FixedRows = 0
    .FixedCols = 0
    For lngRow = 0 To .Rows - 2
      For lngCol = 0 To .Cols - 2
        .TextMatrix(lngRow, lngCol) = CStr(100 * lngRow + lngCol)
      Next lngCol
      .TextMatrix(lngRow, .Cols - 1) = CStr(lngRow) & "/" & CStr(lngRow * lngRow)
    Next lngRow
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  MSFlexGrid1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_Click()
  Dim lngCol As Long
  'calculate subtotals
  With MSFlexGrid1
    For lngCol = 0 To .Cols - 2
      .TextMatrix(.Rows - 1, lngCol) = CStr(GetTotal(lngCol))
    Next lngCol
    .TextMatrix(.Rows - 1, .Cols - 1) = GetTotalSpecial(.Cols - 1)
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Function GetTotal(lngCol As Long) As Long
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim lngTotal As Long
  With MSFlexGrid1
    lngTotal = 0
    For lngRow = 0 To .Rows - 2
      lngTotal = lngTotal + Val(.TextMatrix(lngRow, lngCol))
    Next lngRow
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
  GetTotal = lngTotal
End Function

Private Function GetTotalSpecial(lngCol As Long) As String
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim lngTotal1 As Long, lngTotal2 As Long
  Dim strPart() As String
  With MSFlexGrid1
    lngTotal1 = 0
    lngTotal2 = 0
    For lngRow = 0 To .Rows - 2
      strPart = Split(.TextMatrix(lngRow, .Cols - 1), "/")
      If UBound(strPart) = 1 Then
        lngTotal1 = lngTotal1 + Val(strPart(0))
        lngTotal2 = lngTotal2 + Val(strPart(1))
      End If
    Next lngRow
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
  GetTotalSpecial = CStr(lngTotal1) & "/" & CStr(lngTotal2)
End Function
```

It will load a grid with some values, and when you click on the grid, the subtotals will be calculated and filled into the last row.